# PHP Curl fails on Ubuntu when using PHP 7.2 but works on Mac with PHP 7.3.9

Tags: php, web, curl, encoding

I get the following error only when running `getAnalysis()` on my *Ubuntu* machine while it still works on several versions of *Mac* (including the newest version).
I tried troubleshooting the error by using the [`curl_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) function however nothing was printed out.

---

- **Failed on**: *Ubuntu* with `PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.2` and *curl* `7.58.0`.
- **Worked on**: *Mac* with `PHP 7.3.9` and *curl* `7.64.1`.

**Error:**

```html
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
An error occurred while processing your request.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;179&#46;96cadf17&#46;1580524623&#46;c5f345a
</BODY></HTML>
```

**Code:**

```php
function getAnalysis($text)
{
    $APIKey = "APIKey";
    $URL="https://www.APIURL.com/API/";
    $data = json_encode(array('text' => $text));
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "apikey:$APIKey");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    print("======================================\n");
    print($result);
    print("======================================\n");

    curl_close ($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Can you check this: `if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}` and show the result? A possible explanation may be the openssl lib in the system: it may be older and not understand the required SSL/TLS format.

Comment: @BartoszPachołek So i tried your suggestion but nothing printed out so maybe its coming from the request? weird that it doesn't happen on my mac

Comment: The endpoint must be returning an HTTP code to your request: probably 400, 401, 403 or something else. Fetch this value, it might give you some clues as to the error that is happening server-side. You could also run curl in verbose mode from the command line and see what happens. Dump the headers from the server too.

Comment: Okay so i did some trouble shooting and I found that the script gives this error when I hit 1012 characters on CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. I checked and my mac i can go up to 43000 characters so i believe its some setting somewhere. Still searching

Comment: Have you checked the HTTP return code (since the error has happening server-side) ? This code seems to be incomplete - variable `$data` is not being used in your `curl` request. Sounds like your are sending an empty request (JSON missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally. I just need to change

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Expect:'));
```

The reason was my request was to large and needed to let curl know what to expect